# Why is not updated currentPage indicator on UIPageControl?

Tags: ios, uipagecontrol

I am using the following code to update the `currentPage` indicator in my app:

```
pgcNotification.currentPage = 3;
pgcNotification.numberOfPages = 4;
```

Though, the indicator never changes and always stays in its first position.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you, firstly have to say the amount of pages and secondly the current page. Never in the other way around.

```
pgcNotification.numberOfPages = 4;
pgcNotification.currentPage = 3;
```