# Why is my uipagecontrol not updating correctly the 1st time, but is on the 2nd time through Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uipagecontrol

I have a situation with a UIPageControl embedded in my UICollectionView.  Each page has it's own designated page, which I've split into Collection view cells.  When I swipe over for the second page, the page control indicator stays on 1, and when I swipe to the 3rd page it updates correctly to the 3rd indicator.  When I swipe, back to page 2, the page control is now showing the correct indicator.  It happens every time, only for the 2nd page.

Here is some of my code:

On the main controller with the collection view,

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("cellId", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ItemImageCell

    if let imageURL = self.featuredItem.itemImageNames {
        cell.itemImageURL = imageURL[indexPath.item]
        cell.pageControl.currentPage = indexPath.item
        cell.pageControl.numberOfPages = imageURL.count
    }
    return cell
}
```

And in the cellView class,

```
let pageControl: UIPageControl = {
    let pageControl = UIPageControl()
    pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    return pageControl
}()

override func setupViews() {
    backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    addSubview(pageControl)

    addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: pageControl, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: self, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

}
```

Am I not setting it up correctly?

Edit:

The featuredItem model class:

```
class FeaturedItem: NSObject {

    var itemImageNames: [String]?
    var itemTitle: String?
    var itemHighlight: String?
    var itemDescription: String?
    var itemURL: String?


}
```

Comment: Is it possible that the conditional `let` isn't true?  ie. could `self.featuredItem.itemImageNames` be nil? Are you loading this in the background or such?

Comment: Hi Paulw11, the featuredItem is being loaded via a json parser.  The parsing populates the information in featuredItem, including the itemImageNames String array.  At the page load featuredItem.itemImages is nil, set as an optional in the model object.  I've added the code to see.

Comment: When you set the uiview reload your collection view .

Answer (score 1):

Actually the solution is pretty simple.
You need to assign the numberOfPages first, and then assign the currentPage.

So flip them over and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Since your `self.featuredItem.itemImageNames` may initially be nil, the page control may not be set correctly.  You can try reloading your collection view after the data is reloaded

However, the datasource method `cellForItemAtIndexPath` is a probably poor location to update the page indicator; it is called when the collection view needs a cell, not necessarily when it displays a cell.  It could be called before the user scrolls  in order to prefetch a cell or it may not be called when the user scrolls if the collection view already has that cell cached (e.g. rapid left/right/left scroll).

You should update your page indicator in the delegate method `willDisplayCell:forItemAtIndexPath:`

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView,
        willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell,
        forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        guard let myCell = cell as? ItemImageCell, 
                  imageURL = self.featuredItem.itemImageNames else {
            return
        }
        myCell.pageControl.currentPage = indexPath.item
        myCell.pageControl.numberOfPages = imageURL.count
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion, I think this will work but function returns a UICollectionViewCell, whereas I've created a custom cell called ItemImageCell.  Is there a way to downcast the cell to my custom cell?

Comment: Still showing the same issue, appears to be prefetched.

Comment: Perhaps you need to reload the collectionview once the load is complete

Comment: What's odd is that it works for every other page, including the page in question, it's just the first time through - the current page sets to zero.

Comment: Paulw11's, this is useful knowledge on the usage of cellforItemAtIndexPath and willDisplayCell methods for a UICollectionView.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution to my issue, in this other post.

[Why is not updated currentPage indicator on UIPageControl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28783361/why-is-not-updated-currentpage-indicator-on-uipagecontrol?rq=1)

Specifically, I changed my current implementation of cellForItemAtIndexPath to the following, using the suggestion from Paulw11's solution:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    guard let myCell = cell as? ItemImageCell, imageURL = self.featuredItem.itemImageNames else {
        return
    }
    myCell.pageControl.numberOfPages = imageURL.count
    myCell.pageControl.currentPage = indexPath.item
}
```

and setting the numberOfPages variable prior to setting the currentPage variable.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the changes I made to my code, sorry I'm a new user... is this a better answer?